# Max password size in AIX 6.1

Tags: password, aix

I found on the AIX documentation some rules to set about passwords length :

> **minlen**    Defines the minimum length of a password. The value is a decimal integer string. The default is a value of 0, indicates no
>   minimum length. The maximum value allowed is PW_PASSLEN attribute.
>   This attribute is determined by the minalpha attribute value added to
>   the minother attribute value. If the sum of these values is greater
>   than the minlen attribute value, the minimum length is set to the
>   result.
>
> **Note**: The PW_PASSLEN attribute is defined in
>   `/usr/include/userpw.h`. The value of the PW_PASSLEN attribute is
>   determined by the system-wide password algorithm that is defined in
>   `/etc/security/login.cfg` .
>
> The minimum length of a password is
>   determined by the minlen attribute and should never be greater than
>   the PW_PASSLEN attribute. If the minalpha attribute + minother
>   attribute is greater than the PW_PASSLEN attribute, then the minother
>   attribute is reduced to PW_PASSLEN attribute - minalpha attribute.

But, for consistency, I need to set the max length for password to 12.

I dont understand exactly how to configure the userpw.h to set this max at 12.

There is my actual PW_PASSLEN :

```
#define PW_PASSLEN   ((__extension_status & _EXTENSION_C2)? \
                       max_pw_passlen():__get_pwd_len_max())
```

Comment: I hardly understand why you need to set a maximum length to your passwords. Isn't it the point: having longer passwords to provide better security? I think this is why there is no such thing as a maximum password length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to modify the value for MAXIMPL_PW_PASSLEN in /usr/include/userpw.h, from 256 to 12, but I would strongly suggest you read the documentation in that file, and test this on a non-critical box. If you have access, I'd suggest verifying this with IBM support.

Answer (score 0):

See the /etc/security/user file: this contains the minalpha/minother/etc values you need to change :)

Comment: There is a lot of values (that I use) bot no configuration for the max length.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the second answer; apart from editing the `/etc/security/user` file manually you can also issue the following command:

```
chsec -f /etc/security/user -s default -a minlen=12
```

which sets `minlen` **a**ttribute of `default` **s**tanza in `/etc/security/user` **f**ile to 12.

Note that **all** flags must be specified and the **full** path to the file provided.

`default` stanza is shown in the following form within the file

```
default:
minlen=8
```

The colon is the delimiter and indicator of beginning of a stanza.

Indentation is *optional*.

View attributes with:

```
lssec -f /etc/security/user -s default -a minlen
```

Repeat `-a` switch for multiple attributes as `-a minalpha -a minlen`.

Command syntax and nomenclature is **simple** if you would [*feel*](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/67/6748ede1f3000728f9bde199ebd0dc7d0bcb45f9308393fb334f047a64493d49.jpg) :)